# CSS File not showing up on my local website

Tags: php, css

My local website that I am running using WAMP shows only my php file but not the css file that is linked to it. I have a feeling this is an issue with using php although I cannot use WAMP server unless my website is coded in php.

```
< link rel="stylesheet" href="index.CSS" type="text/css" >
```

This is with the css file being named "index.CSS"

I expect when I link the css file for the properties of the css file to show up on my local website although this does not happen.

Comment: why is it in capital?

Comment: "I cannot use WAMP server unless my website is coded in php" <<<  

I would advise you to seek further information about the WAMP environment _ 
I use WAMP to develop all sites and pages I'm working on but_ apart from the Wordpress work I do_ none of the other files are written in php

Answer (score 1):

if the css file is in same folder

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" type="text/css">
```

if the index.css is in another folder

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="folder_name/index.css" type="text/css">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
```

and

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.CSS">
```

wont be problematic as case doesn't matter here. Make sure the file exists in the same directory. Better yet, make a separate directory just to store styles so your project environment makes better sense. ie

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/test.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally the .css extension is lowercase. Check this and use the relative path to link the file. I hope it will help you.